# How do I redirect a pop-up to a normally loaded page?

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup, thickbox

I am trying to implement something like this:

1. Clicking on a link, a pop-up will be opened, something like sign-up page.
2. On submission, if data is unfilled, an error message will be generated.

But on successful submission, it will be redirected to the main page opened earlier in the browser.

Im using [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) for the pop-up feature. On redirecting using the following code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://localhost/cgi-bin/Ajax/index.pl/">
```

The main page is being redirected, but in the pop-up itself I want the pop-up to die after successful submission and the main page gets refreshed.

Comment: This is actually something you cannot acomplish in perl. You will need HTML/Javascript features to do it. Please show the code you're using to open the popup window and the code making stuff happen there.

Comment: This is da code for POPUP: print '<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/thickbox.js"></script><link href="/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
 print '<a href="new_plat.pl?TB_iframe=true&height=580&width=740" class="thickbox">Add New Platform</a><br/>';

Comment: So it is not a real popup window, but an overlay thing? That's should make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll asume you're using the iFrame solution from the [thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) website. It looks to me that you have to set the `modal=true` part in the URL and use the `tb_remove()` function once the login is completed. The same goes for the AJAX version.

> Optionally you may add modal=true to the query string (e.g.
>   ?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=400&width=600&modal=true) so that
>   closing a ThickBox will require calling the tb_remove() function from
>   within the ThickBox iframe (self.parent.tb_remove()). See the iframe
>   demo for an example, where you must click "ok" to close the ThickBox.

You should therefore just add something like this to your javascript (that you print from perl iirc).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tb_remove();
</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;
      url=http://localhost/cgi-bin/Ajax/index.pl/">
```

Please note that I have not tested this and I'm only referring to the documentation.

Comment: can u help me wid how to call thickbox on submit button in perl ??

Comment: Again, this is not perl. You are talking about JavaScript. I think you could add an ``onsubmit`` handler to your form. Something like `<form action="script.pl" onsubmit="tb_remove()"> ... <input type="submit" value="Login" /></form>`. But if you're talking about something else, you should open a new question and consider daxim's and my edits to this question for the way you phrase it. ;-)